# Unable to blur input element in Knockout-enabled page using Selenium with PHPUnit

Tags: php, selenium, knockout.js, phpunit

I have a page used to edit categories in my application. It uses Twitter Bootstrap for layout, and is pretty simple. It looks something like this:

```
+===========================================
| page header - contains menus, etc.
+===========================================

 Category Editor

 +----+------------+-------------------+
 | ID |   Status   | Name              |
 +----+------------+-------------------+
 |  1 |  [active]  | Category Name 1   |
 |  2 | [inactive] | Category Name 2   |
 | ... more rows ...                   |
 +----+------------+-------------------+
 [Add new row] [Save]
```

(*Items in square brackets are buttons*)

The page is basically one table listing all the categories, along with their ID values and a button which will toggle their status (either `active` or `inactive`). I'm using [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) to bind table rows & their values to my model.

The way the form works is this:

1. To change the state from active to inactive (or vice versa), click the button. This updates the view model and changes the text in the button.
2. To edit the category name, click on it. This will hide the name (which is in a `<span>`) and show an `<input>` element in the same table cell. When you're finished entering the new name, leave (blur) the input element: the updated name will be displayed and the input element will be hidden again.
3. To save all your edits, click the save button.

Everything works, as far as I can tell. I now want to write some tests using Selenium to test this functionality. I'm using Selenium server 2.38.0 with PHPUnit.

The problem I'm running into is that I cannot, for the life of me, get the input elements to blur. I've googled many different things and found a bunch of different suggestions. I've tried:

1. using Selenium's `keyPress` method to send a tab character to the input element (I've tried `"\t"`, `"\9"`, `"\\t"`, `"\\9"`, `'${KEY_TAB}'`)
2. using Selenium's `type` method to send a tab character (same character strings as above)
3. using Selenium's `click` method to click on an unrelated page element
4. using Selenium's `mouseDownAt` and `mouseUpAt` to simulate a mouse button press on an unrelated page element.
5. the `fireEvent` to send a "blur" to the input element
6. the `fireEvent` to send a "focus" to the input element, followed immediately by another `fireEvent` to send a "blur" event
7. the `fireEvent` to send a "focusout" to the input element

Does anyone know how to blur an input element using Selenium?

Edit: For what it's worth, I've narrowed this down to a Firefox issue. The same tests work just fine in Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

This appears to be an issue with Selenium and Firefox 31.0. I was able to replicate it using both the Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox and Selenium Server.

Here's the problem:

In my page markup, I have a table which contains cells which look like this:

```
<td data-bind="click: handleNameClick" class="form-group">
    <span class="item-name" data-bind="text: name, visible: !isEditing()"></span>
    <input required type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: name, visible: isEditing(), hasFocus: isEditing">
</td>
```

1. When the `<td>` is clicked, the `handleNameClick()` method on my view model is called. That method looks like this:

   self.handleNameClick = function() {
       self.isEditing(true);
   }
2. When the `isEditing` observable is `true`, then the `<input>` is visible and the `<span>` is hidden, and when it is `false`, the `<span>` is visible and the `<input>` is hidden.
3. The `hasFocus` binding is there to handle the `blur` event - when the `<input>` loses focus, the value of `isEditing` changes from `true` to `false`, and the `<input>` is hidden.

This last step is working fine in Chrome, both when under Selenium control or when I'm using the form. It is **not** working in Firefox when under Selenium control.

### The Workaround

To solve this problem, I created a workaround where the `handleNameClick` iterates over the items in the view model and sets `isEditing` to `false` before setting `isEditing` to `true` for the current item. My `handleNameClick` method now looks like this:

```
self.handleNameClick = function() {
    // iterate over the parent's items array and set isEditing to false
    // for all of them
    //
    $.each(self.parent.items(), function (i, v){ v.isEditing(false); });

    // now set isEditing = true for this item
    //
    self.isEditing(true);
}
```

Where `self.parent` is the view model and is passed in to the constructor for each item as they're instantiated.

Not the best solution, but it works and probably makes the page a little more resilient.